# vim gg=G html and jinja2

Tags: vim, jinja2

I use `gg=G` to reindent my files in vim. I have jinja2 templates which contain jinja2 expressions and html. The `filetype` is set to `jinja`. When I use `gg=G`, the html get's reindented correctly but not the jinja expressions.

Actual:

```
{% for elem in list %}
{% if elem.foo %}
<div>
    <p>foo</p>
</div>
{% else %}
<div>
    <p>bar</p>
</div>
{% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

Expected:

```
{% for elem in list %}
    {% if elem.foo %}
        <div>
            <p>foo</p>
        </div>
    {% else %}
        <div>
            <p>bar</p>
        </div>
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

How can I change this behavior?

Kind Regards!

Comment: Vim 7.3 does not ship with the `jinja` filetype. Which syntax / indent / ftplugin scripts have you installed?

Comment: this one: https://github.com/Glench/Vim-Jinja2-Syntax

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Jinja plugin's indent script just delegates to the indent method of the default `html` filetype, see [here](https://github.com/Glench/Vim-Jinja2-Syntax/blob/master/indent/jinja.vim).

Unfortunately, though the `indent/html.vim` can be extended with custom HTML tags, the tag syntax `<...>` is hard-coded, so you cannot just configure the `{% ... %}` syntax of Jinja. If you don't find a special indent plugin for Jinja, you'd have to write one / extend the `indent/html.vim` one yourself.